# Overloading operators on python properties

Tags: python, properties, operator-overloading

Is it possible to overload an operator on a python property?  Something like:

```
class Foo( object ):

    @property
    def bar( self ): return unfoobar( self._bar )

    @bar.setter
    def bar( self, baz ): self._bar = foobar( baz )

    @bar.__eq__
    def bar( self, baz ): return self._bar == foobar( baz )
```

without defining a special class for _bar (although in this example, that's probably the best solution...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, operators are applied to the *value* of an attribute (be it supplied by a property or taken from the `__dict__` mapping or a slot), never the attribute itself.

You will have to return a special wrapper implementing `__eq__` and return that, I am afraid.

Comment: Easy enough to add a `Bar` class.  Thanks. I'll accept your answer when SO will let me.