# make python @property handle +=, -= etc

Tags: python, class, properties

from the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property), I see that you can set methods for handling properties transparently:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    def getx(self):
        return self._x

    def setx(self, value):
        self._x = value

    def delx(self):
        del self._x

    x = property(getx, setx, delx, "I'm the 'x' property.")
```

Now assume that `C._x` is a list. In init it is simply set to `[]`. So if I do the following:

```
c = C()
c.x = [1,2,3]
```

`c.x` will be set to `[1,2,3]`. What I want to be able to do now is

```
#...
c.x += 4
```

So that `c.x` is now `[1,2,3,4]`. The example is trivial, but obviously, I'd want the `setx` and `getx` methods to include some sort of processing and checks. Otherwise, using this approach would be silly.

**Edit:** It might be good enough to just use the `__add__` method on `C` to enforce the behaviour, but I wondered if it was possibly to put the behaviour on the property instead of the whole class

Comment: Did you test it? It seems to work just fine for me. Sorry, I tested with `[4]`. More comments and an answer posted.

Comment: No, it should not, if `c.x` is a list, because `[1, 2, 3] + 4` is not legal, you need to wrap the 4 in a list: `[1, 2, 3] + [4]`. Meaning: `c.x += [4]` works.

Comment: It won't. I'd get TypeError: int is not iterable, because I cannot add 4 to [1,2,3]. I could do c.x += [4], but that is not quite what i wanted

Comment: That problem has nothing to do with the property. If you can coax the list into accepting that syntax, the property will work as well. In other words, take the class and the property out of the equation, and work with `x = [1, 2, 3]; x += 4` and get that working. When you have that working, the property will work too.

Comment: Youd need to overload the ````__iadd__``` operator for this one (for the list-type, as is hast no += functionality. Thus, create your own list-type and overload the operator. You can't achieve this inside the property, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959359/overloading-operators-on-python-properties?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't overload operator for a specific attribute, because :

```
c.x += 4
# is equivalent to
c.x.__iadd__(4)
```

So in fact you are calling the `__iadd__` operator of list. If you want to be able to do that, you have to create a new class, extending list, and overload operator `__iadd__` or `__add__`.

```
class SuperList(list):
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        if type(other) == list or type(other) == SuperList:
            return super(SuperList, self).__iadd__(other)
        return super(SuperList, self).__iadd__([other])
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that won't work.

Basically, here's what happens:

```
c.x += 4
```

This code is equivalent to this:

```
var temp = c.x
temp += 4
c.x = temp
```

However, `temp` here will be the list of 3 values, and this code doesn't work:

```
temp = [1, 2, 3]
temp += 4
```

You get:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

So this has nothing to do with the property, and everything to do with the fact that the code needs to look like this:

```
temp += [4]
```

So this works:

```
c.x += [4]
```

This cannot:

```
c.x += 4
```

Comment: So to make it work, I'd had to make an `__add__` method on the class that c._x represents? That's what I figured... oh well :P

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution. You might readjust the behaviour of the `__iadd__`-method.

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # instanciate an empty list of your custom list-type
        self._x = MyList([])

    def getx(self):
        return self._x

    def setx(self, value):
        self._x = value

    def delx(self):
        del self._x

    x = property(getx, setx, delx, "I'm the 'x' property.")

class MyList(list):

    def __iadd__(self,x):
        # if the item is an iterable, extend the list (standard __iadd__ behaviour)
        if hasattr(x,"__iter__"):
            return super(MyList,self).__iadd__(x)
        #if the item is not iterable, append it
        else:
            return super(MyList,self).__iadd__([x])
```

Usage is as following:

```
>>> c=C()
>>> c.x+=1
>>> c.x
    [1]
>>> c.x+="test"
>>> c.x
    [1,"test"]
>>> c.x+=[3,4]
>>> c.x
    [1,"test",3,4]
```

To sum it up: You can't overload the operator inside `C`'s setitem-method, because incrementing is not an operation on the attribute, but the underlying list (as your attribute is just a variable pointing to that list-object). See my comment and the other answers, as well.